# How to check mandatory field whether it is empty or not in Selenium WebDriver using Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, junit4, assertion

I am working on "add new user form" . In this form, there are several mandatory fields. Form will not be submitted when any mandatory field is empty and it will show a validation message like : "Value is required and can't be empty". How can I check/automate the form whether field is empty or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Way 1:
First, write the following method:

```
private boolean isTextPresent(String text){
        try{
            boolean b = driver.getPageSource().contains(text);
            return b;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
  }
```

Now do assertion whether the expected message is present or not on the page by calling the above method:

```
assertTrue(isTextPresent("Value is required and can't be empty"), "Msg is absent/wrong/misspelled");
```

Way 2:
Another way is as follow:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;

private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

try {
      assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("BODY")).getText().matches("^[\\s\\S]*Value is required and can't be empty[\\s\\S]*$"));
    } catch (Error e) {
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: 2nd one is more preferable

Comment: But finally I used 2nd one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `assert` for checking the mandatory field alert is appearing or not, with try-catch

```
try {
  assertEquals("Value is required and can't be empty", driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH_OF_LABLE")).getText());
} catch (Error e) {
 //code for the case when the texts are not same
  verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
}
```

the example is using xpath, but you can use any other locator method for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SoftAssert` to validate all of the mandatory fields in a form by a single `@Test` annotation. Even if any of the assertions fail, it will execute the next line and gives us the all exception caught in `@Test` when we do `assertAll()` at the end.

```
driver.findElement(by.id("submit")).click();
SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
softAssert.assertEquals(firstname.getText(), "First Name is required");
softAssert.assertEquals(lastname.getText(), "Last Name is required");
softAssert.assertEquals(email.getText(), "Email Address is required");
softAssert.assertAll();
```